# What's the sql grammar that is equivalent with DataFrame#coalesce

Tags: apache-spark

With `DataFrame.coalesce` API, we can shrink the number of partitions, I want the same functionality used in spark sql, so I would ask how to write the sql,

In spark sql, I would like the `select * from a` to have only 10 partitions ,which actually may have more than 100 partitions

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the JIRA that exactly does what I want, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24940